# different results out of crontab and manual run

Tags: python, db2, cron

I am running a python script to load some data into db2 database. Yet, I came up with the following module-loading error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 22, in ?
    import DB2
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.3/site-packages/DB2.py", line 12, in ?
    import _db2
ImportError: Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib/python2.3/site-packages/_db2.so.
   Dependent module libdb2.a(shr.o) could not be loaded.
Could not load module libdb2.a(shr.o).
System error: No such file or directory
Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib/python2.3/site-packages/_db2.so.
   Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/python2.3/site-packages/_db2.so could not be loaded.
```

Here is my python module directory:

```
[dbadmin@bldr2:/opt/freeware/lib/python2.3/site-packages]# ls -l
total 800
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system         8142 May 30 2008  DB2.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system        17133 May 30 2008  DB2.pyc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system          119 Aug 09 2005  README
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system        66550 May 30 2008  _db2.so
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     system          256 Mar 31 2009  logging
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system       307200 Jan 13 15:19 python-modules.tar
```

What could be wrong here? And what the fix would be?

**Update:**
I re-ran the command manually, and it succeeds without spitting errors. Yet, the job was originally a crontab entry, like:

```
18 * * * * myscript.py [parameter_list] >cron_nag.log 2>&1
```

The log I pasted out at the top was in this "cron_nag.log". But when I re-ran the command manually, the error was cleared, no more complaining of module-loading, and everything is smooth.

Why the difference between crontab entry and the manual run? I used the same user `dbadmin` to run the command manually as the crontab entry does. They should produce the same content in the log file, shouldn't they?

Comment: Do you have the IBM Data Server Client (or another appropriate DB2 client package) installed?

Comment: @mustaccio: Yes, I have a command-line tool to use as a db2 client. Just type `db2`, I could connect to db2 database. So it looks like a python issue, not a db2 issue.

Comment: Python 2.3 is a *very* old version. Any chance you could install a newer one, such as 2.7?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Regrettably not. We are using Python 2.3.4 for the backward compatible reason. :-(

Comment: If the client is installed, `Could not load module libdb2.a` might mean that the python interpreter does not get the correct environment variables to locate DB2 libraries.

Comment: @mustaccio: There already exists the shared object _db2.so. In this case, is the static library libdb2.a still mandatory? If so, where should I look at to locate it?

Comment: Try to force to load the db2 profile ". ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile"

Comment: @AngocA: I used "su - dbadmin" before manually running the command. Should be the same effect as the crontab, shouldn't it?

Comment: you could inspect your crontab's environment by running some script to expose it: `* 21 * * * python -c "import sys; print sys.path()" > file.txt`.

Comment: Check out `$ man 5 crontab`. You can set variables inside the crontab. For example, you can specify PYTHONPATH='/path/to/include'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force to load the db2 profile. Suppose the instance is at db2inst1

```
 18 * * * * . ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile ; myscript.py [parameter_list] >cron_nag.log 2>&1
```

The problem is that the cron does not load your .profile, and the db2profile is loaded from the .profile.

Also, if you create another shell, that new shell could not keep the db2profile or the connection.

Comment: Guess you are right, Man. I'll wait another 50 mins to verify the result. Still, my gut feeling told me you hit it.

Comment: You can `*/1 * * * * python -c "import DB2; print 'hey!'" > some_log.txt &2>1` if you don't want to wait.