# Shellscript doesn't work in cron job but can run manually

Tags: linux, cron, db2

I have a sample cron where i export data from the table in DB2. My shellscript doesn't work when i include it in crontab but when run manually, it works. cron manually export files while in crontab, it doesn't.

I have tried to include the output of `echo $path` but still doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
rundate=`date "+%y%m%d"`
cd /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/scripts/SQL/output
gzip *.csv
clear
cd /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/scripts/SQL/
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
db2 "connect to SampleDB user user using sample"

db2 EXPORT TO ./output/Sample_$rundate.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL "SELECT * from SampleTable where MODIFIED_DATE=(CURRENT_DATE -1 DAY)"
```

There was no error in running manually or using crontab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [different results out of crontab and manual run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920025/different-results-out-of-crontab-and-manual-run)

Answer (score 2):

`PATH` is not enough - you need to initialize the environment for the user including a number of variables. Those are set by `$HOME/sqllib/db2profile`. 
I suggest to add

```
. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
```

to your script and see if it works.
If it doesn't, please share the exact error reported.

Comment: After inputting export PATH=" /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile” and manually run the script, the script displayed an error "db2 command not found" for lines 8-10

Comment: db2profile sets PATH to include Db2 commands from ~/sqllib/bin. If you will override it again with your value, it will fail to find the binaries. You should `.` (soruce) db2profile *after* you set PATH.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. example of my shell file:
#!/bin/sh
. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
db2 -v "connect to dbName"
db2 -v "call schemaName.procedureName()"
db2 -v "terminate"

Answer (score 0):

Check if cron is running the script as a user that has access to write to the directories you cd into.